# XL4016e1 maximum input current

Tags: circuit-analysis, dc-dc-converter, ac-dc

I have an XL4016e1 dc-dc converter circuit,
the output of the circuit is 12V 6 A .
What should be the current value of the power supply to obtain this current?
thanks

Comment: We don't know an answer to that, as the supplied input voltage is missing. But it really should read in the manual of the product you bought, as we don't know what product you bought and how to use it.

Comment: What voltage input do you want? Do you have the datasheet for this product which is needed for an accurate answer? (Without this, it is still possible to estimate)

Comment: https://pdf1.alldatasheet.com/datasheet-pdf/view/763185/ETC2/XL4016E1

Comment: This is the datasheet of the product, input voltage: 36 V Output voltage: 12V, Output current: 6 A, according to these values, I am considering using a 36 V 10 A power supply for input

Comment: @muhammedhayr: Please post your values to the question. See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a step down converter. Refer to the 24 volt to 12 volt, 6A example in the datasheet.

The power efficiency \$\eta\$ is given at 93%.

The power relationship is
$$P_{in}=\frac{P_{out}}{\eta}=\frac{(12)(6)}{0.93}=77\text{W}$$

Roughly then the input current is
$$I_{in}=\frac{P_{in}}{V_{in}}=\frac{77}{24}\approx3.2\text{A}$$

Of course if your input voltage is different( the efficiency may depend on input voltage), then the input current will be different as well.

From the comments:

> I am considering using a 36 V 10 A power supply

A 36V input would require only 2.2 A.

Comment: Thank you so much
i did as you said, it worked 100% correctly
thanks